# Call colorbox from URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, colorbox

My goal is to open a media asset in colorbox according to the URL I specify in my address bar.

Topic has been discussed enough on the web but I can't seem to get it to work using a url with '?open=true' appended to the end to open a specific video upon loading the url.

HTML CODE

```
<ul>          <li class="media-row">

          <a rel="" class="colorbox-inline initColorboxInline-processed cboxElement" href="/?width=600px&amp;height=400px&amp;title=&amp;inline=true#colorbox-inline-1"><img width="205" height="115" class="imagecache imagecache-lightbox_small" title="" alt="" src="http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/imagecache/lightbox_small/emvideo-vimeo-33340864.jpg"></a><div style="display: none;"><div id="colorbox-inline-1"><div class="emvideo emvideo-video emvideo-vimeo"><div class="media-vimeo" id="media-vimeo-1">
    <iframe width="600" height="375" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/33340864?fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;autoplay=0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>    
          <h3>Sample Video</h3>    
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
</p>            
      </li>
          <li class="media-row">

          <a rel="" class="colorbox-inline initColorboxInline-processed cboxElement" href="/?width=600px&amp;height=400px&amp;title=&amp;inline=true#colorbox-inline-2"><img width="205" height="115" class="imagecache imagecache-lightbox_small" title="" alt="" src="http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/imagecache/lightbox_small/emvideo-vimeo-9445708.jpg"></a><div style="display: none;"><div id="colorbox-inline-2"><div class="emvideo emvideo-video emvideo-vimeo"><div class="media-vimeo" id="media-vimeo-2">
    <iframe width="600" height="375" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/9445708?fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;autoplay=0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>    
          <h3>Custom Video</h3>    
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse
</p>            
      </li>
          <li class="media-row">

          <a rel="" class="colorbox-inline initColorboxInline-processed cboxElement" href="/?width=600px&amp;height=400px&amp;title=&amp;inline=true#colorbox-inline-3"><img width="205" height="115" class="imagecache imagecache-lightbox_small" title="" alt="" src="http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/imagecache/lightbox_small/emvideo-vimeo-33989254"></a><div style="display: none;"><div id="colorbox-inline-3"><div class="emvideo emvideo-video emvideo-vimeo"><div class="media-vimeo" id="media-vimeo-3">
    <iframe width="600" height="375" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/33989254?title=0&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;autoplay=0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>    
          <h3>Keor limpon</h3>    
          <p>Med borla dorla shoe
</p>            
      </li>


      </li>
      </ul>
```

JS

```
var
vars = [],
hash,
hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?')
    + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
       $(".colorbox-inline").colorbox({open:vars['open'] == 'true' ? true : false});
```

Comment: The problem is that I am unable to find a means of opening colorbox. My knowledge in this subject is limited.  From my understanding: I am assigning colorbox to a var, retrieving the anchor hash and then opening colorbox depending on the hash value. Maybe something like http://url.com/#colorbox-inline-2?open=true. But i can't get it to open at all.

Comment: I think you're looking for a chatroom.

Comment: not sure i understand your comment...

Comment: Chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a good start, but the reason it is not working is because you also need to set up a way for colorbox to target each colorbox seperately.  At the moment, colorbox is getting a jquery collection of all elements with the colorbox-inline class, and if open=true, it will always only open the first in the collection.  And since you have not grouped them (by assigning the same non-empty `rel` attribute to them), the remaining elements in the collection are being ignored.

In order for colorbox to target a specific colorbox on the page, give id's to all colorboxes in your html:

```
<a id="cb1" class="colorbox-inline" href="...">...</a>
```

Then in your javascript, instantiate all colorboxes, but only open a colorbox if one of those id's was sent in the url (like this: `http://site.com/page.html?open=cb1`):

```
//get the colorbox id in url (or set to false if not found)
var colorboxId = 
        (window.location.href.indexOf('open=')==-1) ?
            false :
            window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('open=') + 'open='.length + 1).split('&')[0];

//OR: if you prefer using regular expressions, you can tidy
//that up with something like this:
var colorboxId = url.match(/open=([\w\d]*)/) && RegExp.$1 || false;

//instantiate all colorboxes on the page (but do not open any)
$(".colorbox-inline").colorbox();

//if the id of the colorbox was sent in the url, open it now
if(colorboxId!==false) {
    $('#' + colorboxId).colorbox({open:true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks DonamitelsTNT, Do you mind explaining your answer for completeness?

Comment: Certainly, arkjoseph.  And after better rereading your code, my original answer needed more in any case.  I hope this is more clear..

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add a unique class to each anchor...eg: #cb1,#cb2,#cb3

Comment: No, all colorbox anchors have the same class "colorbox-inline" and each one that you want to open with a url parameter must have a unique `id` attribute

Comment: sorry, i meant to say unique ID. ok got it, thanks so much. I am testing now. Ill post back later today!

Comment: This worked excellently. Now just need to figure out how I can pass each unique url to a facebook like button.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll keep an eye out for that facebook question should I be able to answer it.

Comment: Please visit for the ongoing project of passing this link created to facebook from a drupal site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793738/colorbox-url-params-for-facebook-like

Comment: DonametelsTnt, Can you explain //OR: if you prefer using regular expressions, you can tidy
//that up with something like this:
var colorboxId = url.match(/open=([\w\d]*)/) && RegExp.$1 || false;
 and why i would need this?

Comment: You can use you either variable definition.  The 2nd variable definition using regular expressions is more concise, but can be more confusing, so some people don't like using them.  For a detailed intro to regular expressions, check out [this article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). As far as your drupal question, sorry I can't be much help there, I haven't worked with drupal.

Comment: Yea, that's a lot to take in. If I use the regExp, what would the url Look like? [ ?open=cbox2 ] isn't working